# How can I define sealed interfaces in different modules?

Tags: kotlin

I have an interface called `Metric` in `common/` module

```
@Serializable
sealed interface Metric {
        val eventType: MetricType
        val status: Int
    }
```

I have another module called `Foo/` where I have defined a data class which implements this interface

```
@Serializable
@SerialName("Foo")
data class Foo(
    val version: Int?,
    override val status: Int,
    override val eventType: MetricType = MetricType.FOO,

) : Metric
```

Now I know sealed interfaces required you to define the hierarchy in the same module. Is there a way I can define an interface in common module which other data classes can use which are in their own modules. I need to serialize these metric to send to new relic which expects Json. Suggestion would be highly appreciated thanks

Comment: Why do you want this to be `sealed`?  It doesn't sound like that's a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

As you already determined, a `sealed` interface needs to have all its implementations in the same module. Of course it does, that's the whole point of the `sealed` feature: Allowing other modules to add implementations breaks all the safety guarantees.

What you could do, is declare a non-`sealed` interface in your common module, then implement it using a `sealed` interface in your implementation. That'll allow you to use `sealed` safety guarantees in your implementation module only, and only on the `sealed` type, not on the parent type.

In `common`:

```
@Serializable
interface CommonMetric : Metric {
    val eventType: MetricType
    val status: Int
}
```

In `implementation`:

```
@Serializable
sealed interface ImplementationMetric

@Serializable
@SerialName("Foo")
data class Foo(
    val version: Int?,
    override val status: Int,
    override val eventType: MetricType = MetricType.FOO,

) : ImplementationMetric
```